# How can I see previous `at` jobs?

Tags: logs, at

I can use `atq` to see pending `at` jobs, but is there any way to see info about `at` jobs that have already finished, either logs or just confirmation that they were scheduled and executed?

Comment: Beyond the stdout/stderr that will be sendmailed to the user (or the user named in the environment variable `LOGNAME`) as per `man at`?

Comment: Right, I didn't get the sendmail message I normally do, trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember any way other than the resulting email. You could try looking in the shell history for the at job setup.

If you are trying to think of a way to get that in the future, maybe setting an audit rule could do it.

If you are trying to check why didn't you get the email, check if got stuck in the mail queue (`mailq`), look for it in the mail logs, and if the mail service was/is running.