# Is it possible to get the history of commands run with "at"?

Tags: command-history, at

I think the title says it. I would like to retrieve the history of commands run a few days ago with **at** to double check some error we got on an import process.

Comment: Was `sudo` involved? I'm asking because of `auth.log`.

Comment: Thanks. Nope, not sudo.

Comment: Related only: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198435/117549

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `history` command to list the previously ran commands. 
But since you want the commands containing `at` , you can search from within the output of what history will provide to you.

command to retrieve all history

```bsh
$ history
```

commands in history containing `at`

```bsh
$ history | grep at
```

Comment: If the `at` command was executed from a script, it would not be in the shell's history file.  The cron logfile should still mention it though.

Comment: This would also return other commands, e.g. `cat`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, on history i can only find this, but I do not know what was scheduled when entered at :
  919  atq
  918  at 18:00
  917  atq
  916  at 18:00